# Let $f_n$ be a sequence of M-Lipschitz functions. Show that $f$ is M-Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of M-Lipschitz functions on interval $[a,b]$. Suppose $f_n\to f$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$ on $[a,b]$. Show that $f$ is M-Lipschitz too.

I tried everything to prove the statement, starting from the definitions and trying to create a subdivision, but didn't succeed. I don't really see how pointwise convergence could allow us to prove that $f$ is M-Lipschitz, as $\epsilon$ depends on $x$ (so i tried to pass by a subdivision to get the max of $N$). But, it seems to me too difficult as solution for this such of statement. If someone could explain in details (including graphics or examples, please, if possible), I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x,y\in [a,b]$ we have:
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)-\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(y)\right|\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\\
&\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}M|x-y|\\
&=M|x-y|
\end{align*}
Therefore $f$ is $M$-Lipschitz.

Comment: But how are we sure that it holds $\forall x,y \in [a,b]$? The definition of pointwise convergence says: $\forall x \in [a,b]:\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N \ \forall n\ge N$:$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. But the $\epsilon$ depends on $x$

Comment: @Daniil That's equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Everything follows from algebra of limits and the continuity of the absolute value.

Comment: @Theo Bendit Oh, of course, I missed the fact that the limit exists $\forall x \in [a,b]$.. Thank you very much!